# Scala pass function args through to case class copy constructor?

Tags: scala, akka

I have some (Akka) actor code that is using a case class + the copy constructor to update state:

```
def foo(state:StateCaseClass) : Receive = {
  import state._

  {
    case Bar(updates) =>
      context become foo(copy(/* change a limited number of things */))
    // ... other message processing w/ lots of context become foo(copy(...))
  }
}
```

I'd like to add below the import

```
def update = context become foo(copy(_))
```

so that the code can be

```
def foo(state:StateCaseClass) : Receive = {
  import state._
  def update = context become foo(copy(_))
  {
    case Bar(updates) =>
      update(/* change a limited number of things */)
    // ... etc
  }
}
```

but that doesn't compile. I can of course tweak the `def update` a bit to get rid of most of boilerplate, but the `copy` still sticks around:

```
def foo(state:StateCaseClass) : Receive = {
  import state._
  def update(newState:StateCaseClass) = context become foo(newState)

  {
    case Bar(updates) =>
      update(copy(/* change a limited number of things */))
    // ... etc
  }
}
```

Is there comparable syntax that will let me pass through the args to the case class copy constructor and dry out that last bit?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I guess the best solution is to use `context become` explicitly. And I don't recommend you to use the code below.

I guess it's impossible without metaprogramming (macros). You have to create a method with default values for named parameters.

You could always create such method manually like this:

```
def update(filed1: Int = state.field1, field2: String = state.field2) =
  context become foo(StateCaseClass(filed1, filed2))

...
  update(field1 = 0)
...
  update(field2 = "str")
```

But I guess it's not what you want.

The only way to get such method without metaprogramming is... to use method `copy` itself. Method `copy` calls constructor and you could call `become` in constructor.

The code below works, but I **strongly** don't recommend you to use it! It's a cryptocode and it will confuse all other developers.

```
import akka.actor._

trait ReceiveHelper extends PartialFunction[Any, Unit] {
  def receive: PartialFunction[Any, Unit]
  override def apply(v: Any) = receive(v)
  override def isDefinedAt(v: Any) = receive isDefinedAt v
}

sealed trait TestActorMessage
case object Get extends TestActorMessage
case class SetInt(i: Int) extends TestActorMessage
case class SetString(s: String) extends TestActorMessage

class TestActor extends Actor {
  case class Behaviour(intField: Int, strField: String) extends ReceiveHelper {
    context become this

    val receive: Receive = {
      case Get => sender ! (intField -> strField)
      case SetInt(i) => copy(intField = i)
      case SetString(s) => copy(strField = s)
    }
  }

  def receive = Behaviour(0, "init")
}
```

Usage:

```
val system = ActorSystem("testSystem")
val testActor = system.actorOf(Props[TestActor], "testActor")

import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)

testActor ? Get foreach println
// (0,init)

testActor ! SetInt(666)

testActor ? Get foreach println
// (666,init)

testActor ! SetString("next")

testActor ? Get foreach println
// (666,next)
```

Comment: hrrrm, I think I agree with your disclaimer - I'm looking to make the code base more (non-)developer comprehensible, not the other thing.  However, I'm curious: what's this approach look like if there are multiple same type fields?  e.g., `Behavior(intOne:Int, intTwo:Int, str:String)`?